# How do I upgrade salesforce API version?

Tags: rest-api, api-version

How do I upgrade salesforce API version?

If I click on Generate Enterprise WSDL the XML shows API version as 40.0, how to upgrade version to 41.0, I want to use the REST API calls

Answer (score 2):

Rest API doesn't use the wsdl, the soap API does.
For the rest API you define the API version in the url.
example can be base url  +/services/data/v40.0/sobjects/account/describe which will give you a description of the account object and where the v40.0 is your version, you can replace this by v41.0 in your sandbox that is currently in the winter 18 pre release

A good place to test or play around with the rest API is workbench which has a rest explorer. https://workbench.developerforce.com/restExplorer.php

A good other place to find the basics of the rest API would be the trailhead module around this API: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/api_basics/units/api_basics_rest

Answer (score 1):

You can open Winter 18 sandbox and click `Generate Enterprise WSDL`. Check, that your environment is updated to Winter 18

In this case you will be able to do REST API Calls to sandbox environment. You are not allowed to do the same for production, as production environments will be updated to Winter 18 later. Only after that you will be able to use 41.0 REST API on production.